# In Julia, why would `using A: A` be preferred over `import A`?

Tags: dependencies, namespaces, julia

This is an [option for JuliaFormatter](https://domluna.github.io/JuliaFormatter.jl/dev/#import_to_using) and part of the `BlueStyle()` defaults. What advantage does, e.g., `using DataFrames: DataFrames` have over `import DataFrames`?

Comment: The Julia manual still says "Usually, import ModuleName is used in contexts when the user wants to keep the namespace clean." but I think the community has (generally) decided that signaling intention is important: `import` for situations when you're actually extending the functions of the module, `using` for when you're just using it. The manual also says they're equivalent at the language level, so it's mostly a convention thing for communicating intent.

Answer (score 2):

### Importing a package

When you do `using DataFrames` this bring to main scope all the exported functions, which can lead to names confusion like: DataFrames.rename and OtherPackage.rename. If both are exported this can become a problem.
When you import, this doesn't happen, but you need use:

```
DataFrames.rename(df, ...)
```

With `using Package: function` you can use without typing the package name always and avoid name confusions.

It is extremely important when dealing with multiple packages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! The question is a bit more nuanced - using your example, why would one want to do `using DataFrames: DataFrames` as opposed to your example which might be `using DataFrames: rename`